# How can I access URL parameters from within a BasePermission?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write a custom rest_framework Permission to prevent users from querying information that's not of the same company as them. Unfortunately, I can't seem to access any of the URL's parameters from within `has_permission()` or `has_object_permissions()`.

Here's the beginning of my router:

```
# Create a basic router
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
# Establish some variables to assist with nested routes
root_elem = 'companies'
root_elem_id = '/(?P<company_id>[0-9]+)'
loca_elem = '/locations'
loca_elem_id = '/(?P<location_id>[0-9]+)'
# Companies will be the root from which all other relations branch
router.register(r'' + root_elem, views.CompanyViewSet)
router.register(r'' + root_elem + root_elem_id + loca_elem,
                views.LocationViewSet)
```

Here's my custom permission:

```
# Only permit actions originating from location managers or company admins
class IsLocationManagerOrHigher(BasePermission):
    # Checked when displaying lists of records
    def has_permission(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        is_correct_level = False
        # Admins can see every location if their location_id
        # matches a location that's a child of the company
        # specified in the URL
        if request.employee.is_admin:
            is_correct_level = True

        return request.user and is_correct_level

    # Checked when viewing specific records
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        is_correct_level = False
        # Admins can see location details if their location's company_id
        # matches a Location's company_id
        if request.employee.is_admin:
            is_correct_level = True
        # Managers can see location details if it's their location
        elif obj.id == request.employee.location_id and request.employee.is_manager:
            is_correct_level = True

        return request.user and is_correct_level
```

Right now checking `request.employee.is_admin` is only half of what I need - I also need to access the `company_id` from the URL and make sure it matches the admin's location's `company_id`:

```
# Pseudocode
try:
    user_location = Location.objects.get(id=request.employee.location_id)
    return user_location.company_id == kwargs['company_id']
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    pass
```

I've yet to figure out how to pass these parameters into the Permission so that it can perform this extra step. Or perhaps there's a better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you can't pass them in directly (which would be preferable), they are available on the request object:

```
company_id = request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('company_id')
```

`request.resolver_match.args` and `request.resolver_match.kwargs` contain the positional/keyword arguments captured in your url.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Out of curiousity, what would passing it in directly look like? I'm still new to DRF so I wouldn't even know where to begin with passing it straight to the permission.

Comment: I don't know enough about DRF to help you on that.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to the correct response posted by knbk, you can also get the URL parameters using the view object passed to *has_permission* method. Like this:

> company_id = view.kwargs.get('company_id')