# How to access named url arguments in permissions with Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an url config like

`url(r'^user/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', UserView.as_view())`

And a view class like

```
class UserView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [MyCustomPermission]

    def get(self, request, id):
        # code...
```

The permission is like

```
class MyCustomPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view, *args, **kwargs):
    # code
```

How do I access `id` in `MyCustomPermission`? I can't find it from the `request` or from `*args` or `*kwargs`. Documentation doesn't say anything about this. I've tried to look the source code but can't find how to access those named url arguments. Is it even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access URL parameters from within a BasePermission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660423/how-can-i-access-url-parameters-from-within-a-basepermission)

Comment: The question linked above is kind of huge, but the accepted answer is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually that seems to be working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the wrong approach. Rather than trying to access keyword arguments there, you should be using [object-level permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions) and checking [`has_object_permission`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples) in your permission class.

Comment: Actually, I'm working on a case in which using kwargs in permission is better. I want that the authenticated user id is the same as the one in kwargs (I use id in kwargs to get the object under processing).. Using view.kwargs in has_permission() to validate request user id and user id in kwargs is better for performance. Why? cauz has_permission() is called before actually querying database for the object (get_object()). Hence, we save a query if the user already does not have the permission required.

Answer (score 22):

you can access from the view.kwargs.

Answer (score 7):

You can find them in:

```
request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('attribute_name')
```