# Trouble in getting params pk or id in Django rest framework has_permission

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have trouble in getting the params pk in my url, `resources/<int:pk>` in the my django rest framework permission.

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    #extract params pk here
    pass
```

I tried `request.POST.get('pk')` but it returns nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access URL parameters from within a BasePermission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660423/how-can-i-access-url-parameters-from-within-a-basepermission)

Answer (score 8):

You can access the URL parameters via `view.kwargs`

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    pk = view.kwargs.get('pk')
    ...
```